# DNU publish to linux runtime from windows OS

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, dnu

I want to publish using dnu to run on linux from a windows machine. This is required to make docker images, I know the usual practice is to push the source to linux docker and do "dnu restore", but that sounds a lengthy process, and completely against the cross-compat that the DNXCore50 is trying to offer.

The latest dnx runtime now includes a "runtime" for unix/darwin related packages to target the other operating systems. But how to run a publish command that targets linux or rather if there is a way to pull the linux dnx core in a windows machine using dnvm install coreclr??

Comment: The answer of @Shaun Luttin was spot on. You need to install a linux runtime and then publish your app with this runtime. Once you do that you can copy the app to the target machine. The only thing he got wrong in his answer was to switch to linux runtime using `dnvm use`. If you do this on non-linux machine things will stop working since you can execute bash scripts or linux executable on non-linux machines... Just because you may not see deleted answrs:
dnvm install latest -os Linux -runtime coreclr
dnu publish --runtime "C:\Users\%USER%\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-coreclr-linux-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1"

Comment: Awesome thanks, I dint knew how to download the linux runtime in a non-windows machine. Thanks a lot.